# find the heading angle between 2 objects taking into account the forward angle of the initial object

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, artificial-intelligence, quaternions

Ok, so, i've been stuck on this for ages. Im working on an AI that will navigate a tank to a waypoint, defined as a Vector3. the position of the tank is also defines as a Vector3, both these have their Y position set to 0, as to ignore terrain elevation, the current rotation of the tank is also a Vector3, though only the Y rotation is needed, as i'm effectively projecting the 3d position onto a 2d navigational grid.

The AI passes anywhere between -1 and 1 into the control for the tank, which then handles the physics operations. so, i need to somehow calculate the angle, positive or negative in relation to the current heading angle of the tank to the position of the waypoint, then send the rotation value to the controls. At the moment I simply cant get it working, I feel like iv'e pretty much tried everything.

This is my code currently, it doesn't work, at all, and is about the 20th revision:

```
void driveToTarget()
{

    Vector3 target0 = driveTarget;
    target0.y = 0;
    GameObject current0Obj = new GameObject();
    Vector3 current0 = this.transform.position;
    current0.y = 0;
    print(current0);
    print(target0);
    Vector3 current0Angle = this.transform.eulerAngles;
    print(current0Angle.y);
    current0Angle.x = 0;
    current0Angle.z = 0;

    Vector3 heading = target0 - current0;

    Quaternion headingAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(heading);
    print("headingAngle" + headingAngle);
    print("heading direction, allegidly: " + Quaternion.Euler(heading).ToEulerAngles());
    Quaternion distanceToGo = Quaternion.Lerp(Quaternion.Euler(current0Angle), headingAngle, 0.01f);

    float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(current0, target0, Vector3.up);
    float difference = Mathf.Abs(angle - current0Angle.y);



    print("heading angle " + angle);
    if (current0 != driveTarget)
    {
        steeringVal = Mathf.Abs(1.5f-(1f/Mathf.Abs(distanceToGo.y))) * -Mathf.Sign(distanceToGo.y); ;
        throttleVal = 0f;
    } else
    {
        throttleVal = 0;
    }

}
```

--EDIT--

So, I've partially solved it, and now encountered another problem, I've managded to get the tank to detect the angle between itself and the waypoint, BUT, rather than orienting forward towards the waypoint, the right side of the tank orients towards it, so it orbits the waypoint. I actually know why this is, becasue the forward vector of the tank is technically the right vector because of unity's stupid axis ruining my blender import, anyway, heres the updated code:

```
void driveToTarget()
{

    Vector3 target0 = driveTarget;
    target0.y = 0;
    Vector3 current0 = this.transform.position;
    current0.y = 0;
    print("Current: " + current0);
    print("Target: " + target0);
    Vector3 current0Angle = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    print("Curret rotation:" + current0Angle.y);
    current0Angle.x = 0;
    current0Angle.z = 0;

    Vector3 heading = target0 - current0;

    Quaternion headingAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(heading);
    print("heading angle: " + headingAngle.ToEuler());

    float distanceToGo = (current0Angle.y) - headingAngle.eulerAngles.y;
    print("DistanceToGo: " + distanceToGo);




    if (current0 != driveTarget)
    {

            steeringVal = 1 * -Mathf.Sign(distanceToGo);


        throttleVal = 0f;
    } else
    {
        throttleVal = 0;
    }
    Debug.DrawRay(current0, heading, Color.red, 1);
    Debug.DrawRay(current0, this.transform.up, Color.red, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how your code is setup or how the steering works. You may want to look into using the Unity NavMeshAgent to simplify this.

Regardless here is some code I wrote up that takes a destination and rotates an object towards it. All you'd have to do from there is move the object forwards.

```
 Vector3 nextDestination = //destination;
        Vector3 direction = nextDestination - transform.position;
        direction = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z);
        var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        var finalRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime); //smoothes out rotation
        transform.rotation = finalRotation;
```

Sorry if this isn't what you needed. Have you been able to figure out which part of the code is behaving unexpectedly from your print statements?

Comment: so, yep, thats not the problem here, i cant simply rotate the tank directly, i have to call a method in the controller move(float throttle, float turn) with values between 1 and -1, this then translates that to controls for the individual tracks, which apply forces to the rigid body of the tank based on the steering value between 1 and -1.

Comment: what i actually need to do is calculate what direction (+/-) the tank needs to turn and what amount it needs to turn to face the waypoint. then use that as a percentage of 1 multiplied by the sign of the value to to pass to the controller.

i'm not using a navmesh as the terrain is dynamic.

Comment: @LewisDixon For the new issue you are having, what axis of the tank is facing the target? And what axis do you want to face the target?

Comment: i actually got everything mostly working, by adding a quaternion rotation of 90 about the Y axis to the 'current0Angle' variable. it basically works now, with one exception that at one specific heading angle the tank just spins around, i haven't solved this yet, but since it works 99% of the time, i'm not sure if i can be bothered.